# Manga with an overpopulation problem in Hell

Tags: story-identification, manga

I’m looking for this manga where there’s an overpopulation problem in Hell. So a demon chooses the MC as an executor in order to punish and purify evil women on earth so they won’t be sent to hell.

(the image is a picture of a chapter when I was trying to recommend it to my friend a while back, **warning: potentially NSFW**)

> [image]

Answer (score 3):

This is [Oshioki Execute](https://myanimelist.net/manga/99930/Oshioki_Execute), also known as Oshioki X-Cute. That specific panel is from Chapter 4, page 23.

> [T]he manga stars Kenta, an awkward guy who is repeatedly shamed and abused by Riku, the daughter of a popular actress. His ability to see things others can't, combined with the gift of a magic collar from a strange girl named Beatrice, makes him an "Executioner": someone who uses their special power to hit a person's Greed Spots (or G-spots) to save them from damnation.
>
> <sub><sup>[H Manga "Oshioki Execute" Gets NSFW-ish Audio Drama Minisode and Twitter Contest](https://www.crunchyroll.com/en-gb/anime-news/2017/05/02/h-manga-oshioki-execute-gets-nsfw-ish-audio-drama-minisode-and-twitter-contest)</sup></sub>

Comment: And your warning is apt. This is basically porn with little or no redeeming features.

Comment: I checked using very limited (read: 2) chapters, and while the story looks like matching the description on the question, the art style and the mood look a bit different from the image...

Comment: @AndrewT. - It's from Chapter 4.